# C# SQL Library is modifying my queries to fully qualified tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, dns, connection-string

It is changing my queries and appears to be fully qualifying my tables without me explicitly telling it to. Is there a way to stop it from doing that?

Here is the pertinent information as I see it. Let me know if anything else would be helpful.

We had a SQL Server named `serverName`. It's been in production for years. It was migrated away from a Windows 2008 Server to a Windows 2012 Server. The new server's name is `sql_1234_4321` (not the real name but as terrible)

We have nth number of applications that were hitting the old `serverName` SQL Server so we took the old server offline and created a DNS entry for `serverName` that points at the new `sql_1234_4321` hoping we wouldn't have to hit the connection strings for all the apps that were hitting the old server.

This worked for the most part except for some C# ASP.NET MVC apps.

They are using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`.

Connection string:

```
Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=USData; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=appUn;Password=appPw
```

SQL query:

```
select FirstName from Customers
```

Code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
{
    if (parameters != null)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
    }

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    var results = new List<TType>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        results.Add(convert(reader));
    }

    return results;
}
```

I get an error:

> Could not find server 'serverName' in sys.servers.Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Why this error? The only time `serverName` is referenced is in the connection string. My query should just use default namespaces once its on the server. But it appears that my query is being fully qualified at some point in the process as the following:

```
select FirstName from serverName.USData.dbo.Customers
```

I added a linked server `serverName` on the new `sql_1234_4321` server that just points back to itself and this seemed to fix the problem. However, this feels absolutely dirty and makes me wonder if it REALLY is doing a cross server query at that point or if its smart enough to say "HEY! we are hitting ourself so don't worry about going out to the network and making this more expensive than it should be" but i doubt it.

I thought about using synonyms but the problem is we have tables with the server name in them. And there may be queries hitting the server with the server name in them so the following would not work:

```
CREATE SYNONYM serverName FOR sql_1234_4321;
```

So then it would make sense that I'd have to make a specific synonym for each database on the server:

```
CREATE SYNONYM serverName.database1 FOR sql_1234_4321.database1;
CREATE SYNONYM serverName.database2 FOR sql_1234_4321.database2;
CREATE SYNONYM serverName.database3 FOR sql_1234_4321.database3;
CREATE SYNONYM serverName.database4 FOR sql_1234_4321.database4;
CREATE SYNONYM serverName.database5 FOR sql_1234_4321.database5;
CREATE SYNONYM serverName.database6 FOR sql_1234_4321.database6;
CREATE SYNONYM serverName.database7 FOR sql_1234_4321.database7;
CREATE SYNONYM serverName.database8 FOR sql_1234_4321.database8;
CREATE SYNONYM serverName.database9 FOR sql_1234_4321.database9;
CREATE SYNONYM serverName.database10 FOR sql_1234_4321.database10;
```

As you can see, this would be a nightmare to maintain and besides that feels super dirty.

My question is this... At what point is the table name being fully qualified out based on the connection string? Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Curious what happens if you add the schema (dbo) to the query, eg "select FirstName from dbo.Customers"

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient doesn't do that.  SQL Server doesn't do that.  You'll need to troubleshoot further to figure out where the query is coming from, or produce a portable repro of the issue.  And for the reasons you mentioned, and because it's not fully supported, you should not continue using a loopback linked server indefinitely.

Comment: Look for any existing views or synonyms in the database that may be introducing th 4-part names.

Comment: You do not need the Initial Catalog in the connection string which is the default database.  You can add to the string query  "Use USData;" instead when a server has more than one database attached.

Comment: I doubt the DNS entry solution is sustainable. It is probably advisable that you just do the work to correct the connection strings, no matter how many "nth number of applications" are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Browne led me to find the issue.  My query actually had a view referenced and the view had the reference to the old server. Huge oversight on my part to not notice that. Thanks David